# Change auto implemented properties to normal and deserialization with BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, automatic-properties

I have an object with a property implemented like

```
public String Bla {get;set;}
```

After changing the implementation to something like

```
private String _bla;

public String Bla
{
    get { return _bla; }
    set { _bla = value; } 
}
```

on deserialzation, this Property comes up empty.

i have lots of serialized data from the old implementation, and would like to load them with the new implementation

is there any way, to change the implentation to be compatible with older binary files?

**EDIT:**

Some people might run into the same problem, so here's my hackish solution:

the autogenerated fields have a naming convention that is non-valid c# code:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private string <MyField>k__BackingField;

[CompilerGenerated]
public void set_MyField(string value)
{
    this.<MyField>k__BackingField = value;
}

[CompilerGenerated]
public string get_MyField()
{
    return this.<MyField>k__BackingField;
}
```

the quick and dirty fix for me was to create a private backing field called `xMyFieldxK__BackingField` in the source,

and patching the serialized binarydata by replacing all occurences of `<MyField>` with `xMyFieldx` before deserialisation

Comment: What do you mean by "compatible with older binary files"?

Comment: @GregorPrimar: i have lots of serialized data from the old implementation, and would like to load them with the new implementation

Comment: I highly doubt that you can do that with binary deserializaton. You should use XmlSerializer, then you will be able to deserialize older versions as well.

Comment: Actually there is no difference between both implementations. The compiler creates very similar code to the second implementation, if you are using the first implementation. So there must be a reason for you to change the code - e.g. control access to the property. Can you show us some more details of your code? (Further information can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/266593/How-does-it-work-in-Csharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try implementing `ISerializable`

```
    [SecurityCritical]
    public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");

        info.AddValue("name of compiler generated field", _bla);
    }
```

Comment: That is a solution, but must be horrible if working with a large codebase. I have an idea though ;p

Comment: its horrible with a large codebase, but the correct way. i updated my question with my findings

Answer (score 1):

The `BinaryFormatter` serializes the fields, not the properties.

You could possibly get it to work by seeing what the auto-generated field name was in ILSpy or something similar and naming yours that way.

Otherwise as stated by Henrik you would have to write your own deserialization, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245501/deserialization-of-optional-fields-from-binaryformatter) for more information

You can probably inspect the deserialization info by implementing `ISerializable` and special case this field.